# Samsung kies3, device does not support initializing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

I am using my galaxy note 3 with stock software and getting this error, never upgraded in this computer.

Any ideas what the problem is and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Are you using the original data cable? (2) Have you tried re-installing Kies?

Comment: Yes, original cable, I will try to reinstall Kies, though. Thanks!

Comment: Please post back if it's successful or not, so we can add answer. :)

Comment: OK, nothing... Reinstalled, tried different USB ports and cables... No luck.